# Only 24GB of 32GB RAM showing on Server 11.10

Tags: memory

I just installed Ubuntu Server 11.10 64bit and when I execute free -m it only shows a total of 24094.

This is a fairly new build and I was able to see all 32GB on Solaris 11.

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24094        582      23511          0         11        195
-/+ buffers/cache:        375      23718
Swap:        24571          0      24571
```

I am running a Gigabyte 990FXA-UD5 mobo with the AMD 8150 Black Edition proc.

Any input is appreciated.

** Update **

dmidecode is showing the DIMM in the first slot as only 4096 MB

```
Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A0
    Bank Locator: Bank0/1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1
    Bank Locator: Bank2/3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A2
    Bank Locator: Bank4/5
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A3
    Bank Locator: Bank6/7
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of:

```
sudo lshw -C memory
```

I was having similar issues with Ubuntu not detecting my RAM but it turned out to have become physically loose. Weird I know.

Try switching the RAM between DIMMs, is it the RAM or the DIMM? OR Ubuntu? Ya never know!